ListView scrolling as empty below the preceeding widgets even after setting height to the container
enter image description here
This is the code that I wrote. I am trying the make the listview start right below the text widgets and end right before the pay button.The Listview should disappear just below the Text widgets when scrolling up and right above the pay button when scrolling down . Any help is appreciated.
 import 'package:ecommerce/Models/shop_functions.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
 import 'package:ecommerce/Models/shop_functions.dart';

 class Cart extends StatefulWidget {   
 const Cart({super.key});

 @override
 State<Cart> createState() => _CartState();
  }

  class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final palette =Theme.of(context).colorScheme;


 return Consumer<ShopFunctions>(
  builder: (context, value , child) {

    double priceTotal = 0 ;

    for(var val in value.cart)
      {
        priceTotal += val.price;
      }

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        width: 200,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {  },
          child: Text('Pay Rs ${priceTotal}' ,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white
          ),
          ),

        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      backgroundColor: palette.background,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,

        backgroundColor: palette.background,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Cart' ,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 35,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),

            ),

            Text('Check your cart before paying',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: palette.inversePrimary
            ),
            ),



                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: value.cart.length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,

                        itemBuilder: (context, index){
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: ListTile(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                              ),
                              tileColor: palette.primary,
                              leading: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  child: Image.asset(value.cart[index].imagePath)

                              ),
                              title: Text(value.cart[index].name ,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                        ),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(value.cart[index].price.toString()),
                              trailing: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                onPressed: (){
                                  value.removeFromCart(value.cart[index]);
                                },
                              ),

                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),




          ],
        ),
      ),
       );
    }
  );
 } 
}


Image is provided right above the problem description

Try this changes that I have made and please read comments for clarification.
class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  const Cart({super.key});

  @override
  State<Cart> createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final palette = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;

    return Consumer<ShopFunctions>(
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        double priceTotal = 0;

        for (var val in value.cart) {
          priceTotal += val.price;
        }

        return Scaffold(
          // FOR YOUR PURPOSE FloatingActionButton IS NOT AN IDEAL FIT. SO I RECOMMEND REMOVING IT.
          //
          // floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
          //   width: 200,
          //   child: FloatingActionButton(
          //     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
          //     backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          //     onPressed: () {},
          //     child: Text(
          //       'Pay Rs ${priceTotal}',
          //       style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          //     ),
          //   ),
          // ),
          backgroundColor: palette.background,
          appBar: AppBar(elevation: 0, backgroundColor: palette.background),
          floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
            // WRAP WIDGET WITH SafeArea SO THAT 'Pay Rs $priceTotal' BUTTON BELOW IS SHOWN CORRECTLY IN THE iOS.
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text('Cart', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  Text('Check your cart before paying', style: TextStyle(color: palette.inversePrimary)),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,

                        // TRY PLAYING WITH THIS PADDING TO REMOVE THE TOP SPACE.
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        // OR SET THIS,
                        // padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),

                        itemCount: value.cart.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: ListTile(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                              tileColor: palette.primary,
                              leading: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  child: Image.asset(value.cart[index].imagePath)),
                              title: Text(
                                value.cart[index].name,
                                style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(value.cart[index].price.toString()),
                              trailing: IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  value.removeFromCart(value.cart[index]);
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                  // floatingActionButton FROM ABOVE IS MOVED HERE.
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 200,
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                      child: Text(
                        'Pay Rs $priceTotal',
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


I tried  your code. But its still showing the same results.
